# resharper 6 live live templates

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I just defined a live template under "User Templates", however, typing the "shortcut" + TAB isn't doing anything useful.

Is there something that needs to be done to activate the Resharper "code snippet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add it under the correct language?

Look in the live template editor, there are an "Available ..." option just above the code editor.

Comment: yes I am.  Also, I'm checking all options under template explorer

Comment: Which options have you selected?

Comment: "User Templates" under the Live Templates tab.  Also, tried changing the macro contents to be the same as their "if" template. About to restart visual studio again.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Which `Available` options have you selected.

Comment: Got it to work.  Just right-clicked on User Templates.  Selected [New Template], and this time there's an extra text box on the left for "shortcut".  Weird.  Never mind.  Awesome now that it is working.  +1 & a tick for the help.  Thanks.

Comment: oh, to answer your question, "Predefined Templates" and "User Templates".  I may not have tried right clicking again if you hadn't have suggested "which one".